# Push Notifications

Tags: node.js, php, redis

Стоит задача сделать push уведомления на сайте. Используется связка php -> redis <- Node.js -> Sockets -> Client.
Вопрос в том, как указать для Node.js, какому клиенту(авторизированному) послать сообщение?
Вся информация о пользовательских подписках хранится в Mysql.

Comment: У авторизованного клиента есть свой идентификатор. В соединении вот и смотри, если идентификаторы совпадают, то отсылай сообщение :)

Comment: Mojno podrobnosti na palicah? Vot user avtorizirovalsya, v session zanesli ego ID i pro4ee. Kak daliwe sozdati kanal Node.js i otoslati soobwenie etomu useru po ID?

Comment: Сервер не может так просто создать канал к пользователю. Пользователь должен подключаться к серверу и ждать сообщения. Читайте о comet и long pooling.

Comment: Ну у вас уже есть приложение на сокетах? Если нет, то как пример, это - https://github.com/Worlize/WebSocket-Node или socket.io там уже есть примеры. 

Если всё же нужен пример, то будет пример.

Comment: Все таки нужен пример простой. Выходит так что нужно заранее создать все каналы. После авторизации пользователя, нужно проверить к каким каналам он подписан и подсесть на них. Либо со стороны Node.js получать ID юзеров которым отсылать сообщения. Как думаете?

Answer (score 1):

Правильно понимаете, я предложил так: юзер авторизовался, ему присваивается какой-то идентификатор.

Дальше этот идентификатор передается запросом в Nodejs, вот реализация с помощью [WebSocket-Node](https://github.com/Worlize/WebSocket-Node)

Код на автозированном клиенте:

```
var WebSocketClient = require('websocket').client;

var client = new WebSocketClient();

// создаем подключение
client.on('connect', function(connection) {
    // после подключения отсылаем инфу о канале
    connection.sendUTF(JSON.stringify({
        'user': user_id, // пусть будет 10
        'token': user_token
    }));

    // прием сообщений
    connection.on('message', function(message) {
        if (message.type === 'utf8') {
            console.log(JSON.parse(message.utf8Data));
        }
    });
});

client.connect('ws://localhost:8080/', 'echo-protocol');
```

На сервере:

```
//....
var messageToUsers = {};

messageToUsers[10] = [...];

wsServer.on('request', function(request) {
    var connection = request.accept('echo-protocol', request.origin);
    var client_id;

    connection.on('message', function(message) {
       var json = JSON.parse(message.utf8Data); // не забудь добавить проверку try catch

       if(json.client_id != undefined) {
           client_id = json.client_id;
       }

       if(client_id != undefined) {
           var cl_mess = messageToUsers[client_id];

           if(cl_mess != udefined && cl_mess.length > 0) {
                connection.sendUTF(JSON.stringify(cl_mess));
                messageToUsers[client_id].length = 0;
           }
       }
    });
    // ...
});
```

По сути так: на клиенте происходит подключение к серверу, отправляется сообщение с `user_id` и прочей инфой. `user_id` записывается в переменную. При следующих отправках сообщения на сервер `user_id` можно не передавать, т.к. для этой сессии он уже записан на сервере. Вот и всё.

А чтобы выбирать сообщения из базы, я бы добавил "глобальный" интервал, который выбирал все новые сообщения и сортировал по юзерам. Ну тут уже у каждого своя кухня))

Comment: Все это хорошо) но саму суть как связать php + node.js - не уловил.
Допустим, юзер авторизовался и его ID занесен в сессию php.
Дальше как мне этот ID передать на клиентскую часть Node.js?

Comment: @junart так это, нужно в переменную просто занести client_id. Тут хоть ajax, хоть 

    <script>window.client_id = "<?=$_SESSION['client_id']?>";</script>

Comment: Скрыть это возможно от юзера? Потому что можно подставить идентификатор другого юзера и сообщения будут отсылаться ему

Comment: @junart скрыть нельзя. Но и зачем изощряться, когда вместе с идентификатором можно передать хеш, который подтверждает этот идентификатор?

Comment: А хэш из себя что представляет? его проверять как-то в Node.js?

Comment: @junart да всё, что угольно) Пароль в md5, отдельное поле в базе.